# Getting data from Google Maps python object

Tags: python

I've gathered some data from Google Maps API but I'm stuck on getting out the LAT/LNG.

Creating object:

```
loc = self.google_maps.geocode(location)
```

I cannot traverse down this object:

```
pprint(loc)
```

[image]

I've tried:

```
loc.address_components
loc['address_components']
loc->address_components

loc.geometry
loc['geometry']
```

etc which all fail. This feels like such a simple question but I don't know they all fail to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try:

```
loc[0]['address_components']
#   ^ index the list
```

That's because your dict is contained in a list.

The same applies to other dictionaries that deeply nested:

```
loc[0]['address_components'][0]['long_name'] 
# or loc[0]['address_components'][1]['long_name'] for second nested dict
```

Comment: Ah, what a dope I was. In PHP it shows the index key but will have to remember this from now on in Python. Thanks mate. (9 minutes until I can accept)